# Pandas consolidating unique elements based on three different columns combined and adding signature

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below. I would like to get the unique occurances of rows combining three of the values of the columns and then add a 4th column that is a hash of the three columns, using pandas and matching the type below

Here is the dataset:

```
Type   LocationA  LocationB  LocationC  Model
Pipes  Baltimore  Stanford   Vienna     C22
Pipes  Baltimore  Vienna     Stanford   B22
Pipes  Baltimore  Barcelona  London     B22
Tyres  Sao Paolo  Cartagena  Maldives   X23
Pipes  Baltimore  Stanford   Vienna     C22
Pipes  Baltimore  Stanford   Vienna     Y78
Pipes  Baltimore  Stanford   Vienna     NH9
```

so, if I filter for types matching "pipes", I should get the unique elements like below:

```
Type   LocationA  LocationB  LocationC Occurances   Model             Hash(signature)
Pipes  Baltimore  Stanford   Vienna    4            C22,Y78,NH8        f7c360dd7eb4f723a4af838e871f8225
Pipes  Baltimore  Vienna     Stanford  1            B22                0cfe49c08b63158a880d6273ee6cb067  
Pipes  Baltimore  Barcelona  London    1            B22                94c76fd213b5105c59bbb6d34a18079c
```

The hash I use is a plain and simple md5 hash of the three columns.
Shoudl I use groupby and unique? Or unique with some conditional matching?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` method for counting identical rows:

`df['Occurences'] = df.drop(columns=['Model']).groupby(['Type', 'LocationA', 'LocationB', 'LocationC'])['Type'].transform('count')`

Comment: Thanks Tim, that works for occurrence. How can I consolidate the "Model" for similar rows and only list the type given? drop_duplicates only seem to drop all that are row match.